# current time in hh:mm:ss tt formate in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, web

I'm currently doing a web based task. I've got current time in this format.

> hh:mm:ss

```js
        var currentdate = new Date(); 
          var datetime = 
                 currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
                + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
                + currentdate.getSeconds();

        document.write(datetime);
```

How can i get current time in this format:

> hh:mm:ss tt

Where **tt** is milliseconds. [i.e., 09:46:17 89]

Comment: Looking at your code, you would think there would be something called [getMilliSeconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMilliseconds) that you could just add to get those as well ?

Comment: Yeah, after sometime, i got idea about it. Here we met with #HumanWorkingIssues. :-D
@adeneo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

var date = new Date();

var milliSeconds = date.getMilliseconds();

Answer (score 1):

You can add milliseconds to your function, but remember, for milliseconds format must be

> hh:mm:ss ttt

If you only want two units of milliseconds, you must make a rounding

```js
var currentdate = new Date(); 
  var datetime = 
         currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
        + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
        + currentdate.getSeconds() + " " 
        + currentdate.getMilliseconds();

document.write(datetime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this by using the  `getMilliSeconds()` method:

```js
var currentdate = new Date(); 
          var datetime = 
                 currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
                + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
                + currentdate.getSeconds() + " "
                + Math.floor(currentdate.getMilliseconds() / 10).toFixed(0) ;

        document.write(datetime);
```

The `Math.floor(currentdate.getMilliseconds() / 10).toFixed(0)` will make sure that you are getting the millisecond in 2 digit format as expected i.e, `tt`

Comment: Thank You @Rahul . Its the most suitable answer for me. :-)